# How do I add a progress indicator in Shiny from Rcpp

Tags: r, shiny, rcpp

I know how to add a progress indicator in a Shiny app using `withProgress()` (as described [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)). However, given that my long running computation code calls from a package (that I've written) in which most of the code is written using `Rcpp`, I don't know how to return a progress value that Shiny can understand from within the Rcpp code. In my Rcpp code, I'm currently using the ones provided in `RcppProgress` (as described [here](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcppprogress/)), but I'm unsure how `RcppProgress` can communicate with Shiny's `withProgress()`. If anyone has any alternative suggestions, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Hm, to me it seems that this has nothing to do with Rcpp. You are trying to figure out how to instrument a progress indicator in Shiny as a function of something you call from R (which may or may not be Rcpp-based).

Answer (score 0):

Print out your progress and carriage return to the beginning of the same line. Here's a short example that prints out how much progress you've made:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(size_t loop_size) {
  std::cout.precision(4);

  for(size_t i=0; i<loop_size; ++i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    if(i == loop_size - 1) {
      std::cout << "100.0%" << std::endl;
    } else if(i % 33 == 0) {
      std::cout << static_cast<double>(i+1) / static_cast<double>(loop_size) * 100.0 << "%";
      std::cout << "\r";
    }
    
  }
}


/*** R
test(10000)
*/
```